# rss help in iphone development

Tags: javascript, iphone, ajax, rss

Since my last question was deleted  without giving me a chance to reply:  I want to build a similar rss parser feed to: http://misc.inexistent.org/ontd/

Can anyone give me really good tutorials that I could build a similar iphone app for my rss feed.

I can see it uses jquery, javascript, and ajax.

If any can check out the code to head me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are a paid Apple Developer, there is an excellent example project in the developer portal called Top Paid Apps. I've used part of that code in several projects that required XML parsing.

https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/TopPaid/Introduction/Intro.html

That should be all you need to parse an RSS feed and present it in a list view.

Comment: The example provided was a web page, not a compiled app.

Comment: I've purposefully pointed Lane in a better direction than using JavaScript. I have enough experience to know a web app is never as good as an Obj-C native app. If you don't want to use Objective-C, make a website, not an iPhone app.

Also, Dashcode isn't going to help you make it look like a native app, Xcode will. I'd love to see a native-looking app that you've built in dashcode in the iTunes store.

Answer (score 0):

The example you have provided is a web page.

So any of the many online tutorials should help you create a browser based RSS parser that will work in a most web browsers, including iPhone/iPad safari, [example](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2006/09/13/rss-and-ajax-a-simple-news-reader.html).

You might then want to style it look more like a native iPhone app, dashcode could probably help you out here.